# Sort list, based on a full and/or partial match

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to return a sorted list, using a list of either full matches or prefix matches. I can demonstrate a function `sorted_schedule` that will work with full matches only.

```
# This is the defined order (CONSTANT)
WEEKDAY_ORDER = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']

# This is my working function
def sorted_schedule(s):
    return sorted(s, key=lambda k: WEEKDAY_ORDER.index(k))

# Given an unordered set, return a sorted list
schedule1 = set(['Wednesday', 'Friday'])
print(schedule1)  # set(['Friday', 'Wednesday'])
print(sorted_schedule(schedule1))  # ['Wednesday', 'Friday']
```

However, it doesn't work for prefix matches—that is, where the beginning is a match in `weekday_order`, but remainder of the item is irrelevant.

```
schedule2 = set(['Wednesday afternoon', 'Friday'])
print(sorted_schedule(schedule2))
# ValueError: 'Wednesday afternoon' is not in list
```

I have a guess that I need to provide a different function for `key`, but I'm not sure how to make this.

Comment: Is your day name always the first in the fraze? No frazes such as "this Wednesday" or "next Friday"?

Comment: always prefix, never "this Wednesday"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the first part of the string. (`Wednesday` from `Wednesday afternoon`)

```
>>> WEEKDAY_ORDER = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
>>>
>>> def sorted_schedule(s):
...     return sorted(s, key=lambda k: WEEKDAY_ORDER.index(k.split()[0]))  # <---
...
>>> schedule2 = set(['Wednesday afternoon', 'Friday'])
>>> print(sorted_schedule(schedule2))
['Wednesday afternoon', 'Friday']
```